# JQuery Bigtext plugin - Make it work with tables?

Tags: jquery, plugins, html-table

I would appreciate some help with making the JQuery Bigtext plugin work with HTML Tables, so that the text in each cell is as large as it can be. I just need help with getting the plugin to work with tables. I should be able to manage the CSS myself :)

Reason I need it to work with tables is that I´m using PHP with MySQL to get query results. Those results should fill out rows and columns depending on options selected in an html form.

I've tried a couple of tests with [BigText in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachleat/WzN6d/), but didn´t have any luck.
I've also read the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText/blob/master/README.markdown) with no luck.

Comment: Looks like it's working, mate.  I'm browsing your jsFiddle with Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, the plugin is working with the <div> element. But I´d like to use an HTML Table, with multiple rows and columns.

Here is an example table:  
`<table id= "bigtext">  
    <tr>  
        <td>The elusive</td>  
        <td>BIGTEXT</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>   
        <td>plugin exclusively</td>  
        <td>captured on film</td>  
    </tr>  
</table>`